# How to recommend K similar items to a user who has bought N items?

Tags: mahout, recommendation-engine

Suppose a user buys n items from my website; I need an algorithm or a method (using Mahout maybe? How?) so that I can recommend k similar items to the user. I don't have user ratings.
The k recommendations need to be based upon the user's buying history (his n items).

The items have fields "name","author","keywords" for example, I need to recommend the most similar items. What happens if I add user ratings along with this? How would I take that into account?

I've read the Mahout docs, but it seems to always need some sort of ratings. How will I provide ratings, if say, I have had only a couple of customers so far?

Comment: Am I actually talking about some kind of content-based recommendation? Do I need to cluster my data according to their content? If yes, how? I'm quite baffled.

Comment: I found some insight here too:
A simple method is described that involves creating your custom MyItemSimilarity which will compare the two items and assign a similarity rating, along with a Recommender of your choice. 
http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Content-based-Recommender-Implementation-td913981.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *perfect* way to build a recommender.

**Recommendations without user ratings**
Calculate the item-item similarity according to the keywords, name and author. Then you can propose the most similar items not seen yet. As items don't change often, you can store the similarity-table somewhere.

**Recommendations with user ratings**
If you don't want to have user ratings, you could also store the view-history of a user. This results in a "boolean" rating (only having "seen" and "not seen"). With this pseudo-rating, you can generate recommendations with user-similarity. Users having seen similar things are similar.

For some lecture, I strongly recommend you the book [Mahout in Action](http://manning.com/owen/). It contains a lot of information about how to use Mahout.